# Extract number data from HTML with RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

I need to extract a number from an HTML page and convert it into a variable in my test case.

The problem is that there is no ID directly to this element, here is the HTML code, I want to get the 54 (that number can change that's why I need to identificate him with another way), I tried `Get Text` by using "resultat" but I get "54 ligne(s) trouvée(s)" but I only want "54":

```html
<div class="tab-interpage> == $0
        <div class="resultat">
             <b>54</b> 
             ligne(s) trouvée(s)
        </div>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have other options how to locate an element, see [Locating elements section in Selenium Library](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Locating%20elements).

This might be a situation that requires xPath, I can imagine this one works (but I don't see the whole DOM, so I can't be 100 % sure):

```
//div[@class="resultat"]/b
```

combined with the keyword:

```
${var}=    Get Text    //div[@class="resultat"]/b
```

Obviously if there're more div elements with class "resultat", you might run into problems here. In this case, explore the DOM a bit more and see what are some other ways you can get to the element you need.

---

I think it'd be much more readable if the HTML elements had proper attributes like:

- form with class attribute
- unique ids usually work best

Comment: It works !! I get the Text ! Does Robot Framework knows it is a number or I have to convert it ? Thank you very much :D

Comment: @Chanchan It will be a string if your application requires you might have to convert it to `int` or other types. For that there are keywords in the BuiltIn library.